# Swift facebook login, unable to get values,

Tags: facebook, swift, ios9

I have a method where is variable result and I can't get from there values for email, name etc...

```
func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "name, email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                print(result)

            }
        })
    }
}
```

I tried some coding but always getting an err. The result have a structure like this.

```
{email = "xy@icloud.com";
id = xxx;
name = "name surname";}
```

How to get it as array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry. I am incredibly stupid.

```
print(result["email"], result["name"])
```

Comment: You don't have to use `SwiftyJSON` for this.